# A better code to make an empty square with using numbers

Tags: python, python-3.x

hi i want to make an empty square with numbers and i have the code like this:

```
L = input ('input your numbers = ')
M = (L-2) * ' '
P = L - 1
x = ""
y = ""

for a in range(1,L+1): 
    x = x + str(a)
print x
for b in range(2,L):
    print str(b) + M + str(P)
    P-=1
for c in range(L,0,-1):
    y = y + str(c)
print y
```

i just want to know if you guys can help me with the better code.. idk i just feel not satisfied enough with my code.. maybe you can give me an alternative ways (add some condition or maybe create increment and decrement number only use 1 function ?)
btw this is the first time to ask in here hehe

thx

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it would be better suited on [codereview.se]

Comment: with some tidying up, I think it may be a good question for Code Review, but please first read our [How to ask a good question](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) page so you know what needs to be tidied up.

Comment: ok i'm sorry.. thx for the advise
it won't happen again in the future

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly the same output as yours (due to `print` placing space after each digit), but example how to accomplish the same by detecting edge and calculating value:

```
n = input('> ')
m = n-1

for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n):
        if i == 0 or j == 0:   # top or left edge
            print 1+i+j,
        elif i == m or j == m: # right or bottom edge
            print 2*n-1-i-j ,
        else:                  # inside
            print ' ',
    print
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string = map(str,range(1,L+1))
print ''.join(string)
print '\n'.join([ i+M+j for i,j in zip(string[1:-1],string[1:-1][::-1])])
print ''.join(string[::-1])
```